# What join columns should I take for ACDOCA and JVSO1 SAP tables?

Tags: azure-synapse, sap-erp

I have fetched two SAP ERP tables into Azure Synapse: `ACDOCA` and `JVSO1`.

Now I need to join these two tables. And the column `EBELN` is required to be in join condition, also both tables have around 40% of `EBELN` empty. Because of these empty values, these two tables produce a lot of data (In Billions).

What I have tried: I have picked one more column `EBELP` and joined both tables based on these two columns:

```sql
WHERE ACDOCA.EBELN = JVSO1.EBELN AND ACDOCA.EBELP = JVSO1.EBELP
```

But even after this condition, I am getting a lot of data.

**What I want:**

I want to join these two tables and have less amount of data (Not in Billions). Can you please suggest me more columns in both tables so that I can join both of the tables correctly with lesser amount of data.

Thanks

Comment: which data actully you want common dat from both table or common data from 1 table and all data from another table?

Comment: @PratikLad I want common data from both table

Comment: if 40% of EBELN empty, then how adding EBELP column as joining condition will help ? Also you are joining with `and` operator between conditions. How this will help with empty EBELN data?

Comment: columns based on which you are joining the table if it has empty or null values the join condition will skip those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Joining conditions
`on acdoca.ebeln=JVSO1.ebeln and acdoca.ebelp=JVSO1.ebelp` and `on acdoca.ebeln=JVSO1.ebeln` will give same result for rows with null values.  I repro'd this with sample data.

**Input data** with null values:

| ebeln | EBELP |
| --- | --- |
| null | A |
| AA | AA |
| null | B |

[image]

**Joining tables based on ebeln fields:**

```sql
select * from acdoca full outer join JVSO1 on 
acdoca.ebeln=JVSO1.ebeln
```

[image]

**Joining tables based on ebeln and ebelp fields:**

```sql
select * from acdoca full outer join JVSO1 on 
acdoca.ebeln=JVSO1.ebeln and acdoca.ebelp=JVSO1.ebelp
```

[image]

- Query should be written in such a way whenever `ebeln` field is null, condition should be on matching `ebelp` fields *JOIN of tables* should happen.

```sql
select * from acdoca full outer join JVSO1 
on
(acdoca.ebeln is not null and acdoca.ebeln=JVSO1.ebeln) 
or 
(acdoca.ebeln is null and acdoca.ebelp=JVSO1.ebelp)
```

or

```sql
select * from acdoca full outer join JVSO1 on 
(isnull(acdoca.ebeln,acdoca.ebelp) =
isnull(JVSO1.ebeln,JVSO1.ebelp))
```

Even when you add other matching columns, joining conditions should be like above queries.